# Emotion CSS-in-JS ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, core-motion, emotion

I'm trying to use, the [css prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) from the [emotion library](https://emotion.sh/) in a project that I overtook after another dev. In the documentation they say that one way how to get started with the `css prop` is using **Babel Preset**. I have added the `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` to the `presets` in my `babel.config.js` but I'm getting this very interesting error. **ReferenceError: exports is not defined**.

I have not been able to find any thread that would refer to this error being associated directly with the `emotion library` so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in basic babel setup.

Is it maybe possible that using `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc` would cause such error?

Thanks, for your time!

**Here is my babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = (api) => {
api.cache(false);

return {
    presets: [
    '@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop',
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
        modules: false,
        loose: true,
        targets: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        },
        },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: [
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
    [
        'transform-imports',
        {
        lodash: {
            transform: 'lodash/${member}',
            preventFullImport: true,
        },
        },
    ],
    ['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'lib', style: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    ],
};
};
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried moving '@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop' to bottom of the list?

Comment: in babel 7.x it will pickup `babel.config.js` in the root, otherwise `.babelrc`. also that error shows when the code is not going throught a transpiler such as babel, make sure your webpack is using babel-loader

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just ran into the same issue so maybe my workaround will save someone some time even if you've moved on.

After experimenting with different `babel.config.js` preset/plugin combinations, the “ReferenceError: exports is not defined” error occurred when using `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` with `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`.

It looks like `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` has to run after `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` but Babel plugins run before presets. To get around that, I removed `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop`, installed the individual plugins from its [source code](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-css-prop/src/index.js), and added those before `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` in the plugins array (with “___EmotionJSX” as the `pragmaName`).

In your case, the updated config file would look like this:

```js
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(false);

  return {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          modules: false,
          loose: true,
          targets: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
          },
        },
      ],
      '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: [
      'react-hot-loader/babel',
      [
        'transform-imports',
        {
          lodash: {
            transform: 'lodash/${member}',
            preventFullImport: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      ['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'lib', style: true }],
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
      [
        '@emotion/babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic',
        {
          export: 'jsx',
          module: '@emotion/core',
          import: '___EmotionJSX',
        },
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
        {
          pragma: '___EmotionJSX',
          pragmaFrag: 'React.Fragment',
        },
      ],
      'emotion',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    ],
  };
};
```